# How to use path alias in a react project with Typescript + Jest

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I have been using jest for unit testing in my react project (typescript). Now I have enabled path alias in webpack and tsconfig. In order to use path alias with jest, I have followed this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@martin_hotell/type-safe-es2015-module-import-path-aliasing-with-webpack-typescript-and-jest-fe461347e010). But I am getting this error when I run my tests:

[image]

Here is my webpack configuration to enable path alias:

```
alias: {
  'ui': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/framework/components/ui')
}
```

Here is my jest configuration to enable path alias (package.json)

```
"moduleNameMapper": {
    "ui": "<rootDir>/src/framework/components/ui/"
}
```

I also tried this version from the tutorial:

```
"moduleNameMapper": {
   "^ui/(.*)$1": "<rootDir>/src/framework/components/ui/$1"
}
```

Finally here is my tsconfig.json configuration:

```
"baseUrl": "src",
"paths": {
  "ui": ["framework/components/ui"]      
}
```

When I run my test, jest actually resolves the path alias. But it fails to pick up components exposed as default. For e.g this line:

```
import Button from './FormComponents/Button';
```

fails because 'Button' is exported as default from its module.

I hope my question makes sense. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 31):

Use `ts-jest` https://huafu.github.io/ts-jest/user/config/#jest-config-with-helper:

```
// jest.config.js
const { pathsToModuleNameMapper } = require('ts-jest/utils');
// In the following statement, replace `./tsconfig` with the path to your `tsconfig` file
// which contains the path mapping (ie the `compilerOptions.paths` option):
const { compilerOptions } = require('./tsconfig');

module.exports = {
  // [...]
  moduleNameMapper: pathsToModuleNameMapper(compilerOptions.paths /*, { prefix: '<rootDir>/' } */ )
};
```

Comment: this works! I needed the prefix, but totally works, thanks so much!

Comment: umm, how do i do it with the base url ?

Comment: @gaurav5430, what is not working with your setup? Can you provide an example of your config? I'm guessing you need to change the prefix parameter and adjust it to your need

Comment: got the base url handling here: https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/getting-started/paths-mapping/ , need to add modulePaths

Answer (score 29):

Try

```
"moduleNameMapper": {
   "^ui/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/framework/components/ui/$1"
}
```

It shouldn't have $1 in the regex as $1 is used in the replacement string to insert the captured text.

E.g. in your example, "Button" would be captured by the (.*) and then used in place of $1 in the replacement string.