# The @ scoping isn't working in a Typescript project

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to improve my code by applying the [`@` scoping mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51614395/5530965) so that I can just use `@` to mean `./src/`:

```json
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2017",
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*"]
}
```

My file structure looks like:

```
<root>
  dist/
  libraries/
  node_modules/
  src/
    generated/
    clients/
    tests/
      clients/
        session.test.ts
      constants/
    util/
  package.json
  tsconfig.json
```

Inside of `session.test.ts` I would do something like:

```js
import { Constants } from '@/tests/constants';
import { Util } from '@/util';
```

But I keep geeting this error:

> Cannot find module '@/tests/constants' from 'src/tests/clients/session.test.ts'

What am I doing wrong here?

### EDIT

With this setup, VS Code doesn't complain. I only get the error when running my tests with:

```bash
jest ./src/tests/**/*.test.ts --coverage --runInBand
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think you need more than just `@`. You probably should add as `@util/*` and `@tests/*` and so on (with the appropriate paths).

Comment: @JeffMercado I basically just copied and pasted what I saw on a NextJS project I was working on `"@/*": ["./src/*"]`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use path alias in a react project with Typescript + Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51080947/how-to-use-path-alias-in-a-react-project-with-typescript-jest)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @JBallin for your comment. That led me to fix my issue.

My `jest.config.js` is now:

```js
/** @type {import('ts-jest').JestConfigWithTsJest} */
const { pathsToModuleNameMapper } = require('ts-jest');
const { compilerOptions } = require('./tsconfig');

module.exports = {
  coverageDirectory: 'coverage',
  coverageProvider: 'babel',
  coverageReporters: ['json', 'text', 'lcov', 'clover', 'cobertura'],
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  testSequencer: './custom-sequencer.js',
  transform: { '^.+\\.ts?$': 'ts-jest' },
  moduleNameMapper: pathsToModuleNameMapper(compilerOptions.paths, {
    prefix: '<rootDir>/'
  })
};
```

The fact that VS Code can tell that the scoping worked but running my tests was where the error was happening should've told me that the problem was with how jest was configured.