# How to read absolute path when using Jest?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, vite, ts-jest

I have a react application with Vite framework in which I want to write the test cases using Jest.
But the issue is jest is unable to read absolute path used in the import statements.

Attaching tsConfig file and jest config file for reference.

**tsconfig.json**

```
    {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "types": ["./types/fin", "./types/heap", "node", "jest", "vite/client", "vite-plugin-svgr/client"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": false,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "src/*": ["src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src", "src/config/authConfig.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "build"]
}
```

**jest.config.json**

```
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  collectCoverage: true,
  collectCoverageFrom: ['./src/**'],
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  moduleNameMapper: { '^.+\\.(css|less|gif|jpg|jpeg|svg|png)$': 'module.exports = {};' },
};
```

Please have a look on the config files and suggest what can done in this.

**Error:-**

```
● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module 'src/pages/page1' from 'src/components/Modules/Module1.tsx'

    Require stack:
      'src/components/Modules/Module1.tsx'
      'src/components/Modules/Module1.test.tsx'

      1 | import { useState, useEffect, useContext, useRef } from 'react';
    > 2 | import { dummy } from 'src/pages/page1';
        | ^
      3 | import { dummy2 } from 'src/pages/page';

      at Resolver._throwModNotFoundError (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/resolver.js:427:11)
      at Object.require (src/components/Modules/Module1.tsx:2:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/Modules/Module1.tsx.test.tsx:2:1)
```

Comment: Please see if the following answers your question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51080947/how-to-use-path-alias-in-a-react-project-with-typescript-jest

Comment: @IgorDanchenko Still getting the same error.

Comment: You need to add the path aliases to jests `moduleNameMapper` config. Also, `ts-jest` is more trouble than it is worth.

Comment: @morganney Can you show some example how it can be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issue in my case I just added this in jest.config.js

```
moduleNameMapper: { '^.+\\.(css|less|gif|jpg|jpeg|svg|png)$': 'module.exports = {};', 'src/(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/$1' },
```

Look at the last src part which I have added.